# Manage pool of sibling processes in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, process, application-pool

I have a Bash script that runs a web server. The idea is that we can have multiple web servers running at the same time each with one application and database.

The web servers are assigned sequential TCP ports. I don't want the same application and database pair to be run at the same time. So if I run:

```sh
runserver.sh myapp db1

runserver.sh myapp db1  # This one must give an error saying it's already running
```

How can I know if I have a repeating running application?

I have seen that running `ps -eo pid,command` I can get the PID and command that's running, so I though in maybe creating a file with the PIDs of the processes I run, but I think this could be a problem on some edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Come up with a unique filename based on the `(application, database)` pair, and use the Linux-standard [`flock(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) to lock that file and control access to it.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

app=$1
db=$2
lockfile=/tmp/${app}-${db}.lck

# Use an exit value your application won't generate to indicate locking failure
lockerr=50

flock -E $lockerr --exclusive --nonblock "$lockfile" "$app" "$db"
if [[ $? -eq $lockerr ]]; then
    echo "Error: '$app $db' is already running." >&2
fi
```

Example:

```sh
$ ./runserver.sh ./myapp.sh foo &
[1] 1234
$ ./runserver.sh ./myapp.sh foo
Error: './myapp.sh foo' is already running.
```

Comment: I don't understand why there's the `"$app" "$db"` at end of command. The server creates a directory, would it be better to put a lock in this directory and let only the server use the lock? Or if I lock the on the Bash script do the jobs can access the directory too?